# I knew I should have gone with a spastic colon!

Tags: grammar

> -Dad, I don't think I should go to school today! I have a fever.
>   -Oh, yeah?Hmm, feels like a spelling test! Come one, I'll drive you to school.
>   -**I knew I should have gone with a spastic colon!**
>
> TV Show: Alexa and Katie!

What is the difference between the following?

*I **knew** I should have gone with a spastic colon!*

*I **know** I should have gone with a spastic colon!*

P.S.: We use "should have + p.p." to talk about a regret or something like that in the past but we mention to that regret in the present. But here it is mentioned to the past!

Comment: For anyone who needs clarification, the child is faking an illness, reminiscing that he should have decided on the spastic colon affliction in order to trick his dad.

Answer (score 3):

What he regrets is that he chose a fever even though he knew **at that time** that it was a pretty weak excuse.